# How do I change the external DNS not kubernetes(CoreDNS)?

Tags: kubernetes, coredns, kubernetes-dns

My pods can't find the URL https://nfe.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfe/services/NFeAutorizacao4.

I did a test and added the DNS `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` in the `/etc/resolve.conf` file of one of the pods, and the URL is found.

The file `/etc/resolve.conf` looks like this

```
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
nameserver 10.245.0.10
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
options ndots:5
```

My question is:

Is there a correct way to correct the cluster DNS and leave it in an automated way?

We use CoreDNS,
Corefile:

```
.:53 {
    errors
    health
    ready
    kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
      pods insecure
      fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
    }
    prometheus :9153
    forward . /etc/resolv.conf
    cache 30
    loop
    reload
    loadbalance
    import custom/*.override
}
import custom/*.server
```

Comment: Are you able to find ANY DNS names?  Your 10.x.x.x address is a local address inside your network.  Is there a reason they would be filtering your requests?  Why not just delete that line?

Comment: The address 10.245.0.10, is the IP of the CoreDNS Service in the cluster.This information is entered into the pod's 'resolve.conf' file automatically upon pod creation.
I can find the mentioned address only after adding the Google DNS(8.8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4) in the resolve.conf file.

Comment: @Guilherme Is your issue  solved ? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that by creating the ConfigMap 'coredns-custom', which is the coredns default

It looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns-custom
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  custom.server: |
    specific-domain:53 {
      log
      forward . 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
    }
```

replace 'specific-domain' with some specific domain or '*'.